# Install Socat on Mac

Tags: macos, socat

I would like to know how can I install Socat on my Mac (lion) ?

I tried to find an How To via Google but I didn't find anything.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 47):

Use [brew](http://brew.sh/). After installation, *socat* is available running this command:

```
brew install socat
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org). After installation, socat is available running following command:

```
sudo port install socat
```